# mongodb php get array value

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I am trying to get ONE value from a sub document of a stored doc.
a sample document looks like this and I'm trying to get the value "doc2":

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52060cae8b080ed4170063d3"),
"form_id" : "5204c6dca0875b6a1545f436",
"update" : false,
"values" : [{
  "5204c71a8b080e6c190000bb" : "doc2"
}, {
  "5204c7638b080e6c19006b06" : "that one too"
}, {
  "form_id" : "5204c6dca0875b6a1545f436"
}, {
  "btn_submit" : "Save"
}]
}
```

so far my code looks like this:

```
try {
   $connection = new Mongo();
   $database = $connection->selectDB('forms');
   $collection = $database->selectCollection('instance');
} catch(MongoConnectionException $e) {
 die("Failed to connect to database ".$e->getMessage());
}
$value = $collection->findOne(array('_id' =>new MongoId($instid)),array('values.'.$fid));
```

$instid is passed in and is form_id in the document. And $fid is passed in and is the key in the values array in the document

and I'm getting this:

```
{ ["_id"]=> object(MongoId)#15 (1)
{ ["$id"]=> "52060cae8b080ed4170063d3" } 
 ["values"]=> 
 { [0]=> { ["5204c71a8b080e6c190000bb"]=> "doc2" }
 [1]=> array(0) { } 
[2]=> array(0) { } 
[3]=> array(0) { }
} }
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting data in form of multidimensional Array, So you should use

```
print_r($value['values']['0']);
```

This will return

```
 Array ( [5204c71a8b080e6c190000bb] => doc2 )
```

And if you only want to echo out doc2 then you can use foreach statement

```
foreach($value['values']['0'] as $x)
{
    echo $x;

}
```